# Access JSON Key in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out all the `cpe_mac` fields of my JSON data.

## I have

```
# Last updated : BH | 8/31/2016

import requests
import json

ssc_ip = raw_input("What is your SSC Host (Ex. http://172.19.242.32:1234/ ) ? : ")
if not ssc_ip:
    ssc_ip = 'http://172.19.242.32:1234/'

cpe_num = raw_input("How many CPE(s) you want to delete ? : ")
print '\n'

url = ssc_ip+'vse/vcpes'
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
# print json_data

for x in json_data:
    print json_data.cpe_mac
```

---

I kept getting

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'cpe_mac'`

---

## Trying

`print json_data['cpe_mac']`

I got

`KeyError: 'cpe_mac'`

Comment: That's not how you access dictionary keys. Also, you're iterating over `json_data` but then not using the iterated object.

Comment: you need to use dictionary notation: `json_data['cpe_mac']` but what are you expecting `x` to be doing?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen : Did that, I got `KeyError: 'cpe_mac'`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Based on the number of Python questions you've asked in the last hour. I think you really need to sit down and refresh yourself on the basics of how Python works.

Comment: Can you add the JSON Text structure as text? After you deleted the image, it was difficult for me to understand how @IronFist knew what the data structure looked like... until I saw the history of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested dictionary, it should be:

```
for x in json_data['data']:
    print x['cpe_mac']
```

Comment: @ihue .. it's Python 101 lectures :)...Dictionary basics, you need to look on your data format so you can get the right value you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how to access a dictionary item. The dictionaries of interest are contained in a list (accessible via key `data`) inside the parent dictionary `json_data`.

You should do:

```
for x in json_data['data']:
    print x['cpe_mac']
```

Comment: @IronFist Nested in a list (at key `data`) in the parent dictionary `json_data`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye : How do I do it, if I want to print only the first 5 cpe_mac ?

Comment: @ihue That's a completely different question. You really need to take the time to try things before turning to SO.